# Calculate Pearson correlation coefficient for only 1 column of array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I have an array that has shape ~`(700,36000)`and would like to calculate the pearson correlation coefficient for only a specific column (against all other columns) but thousands of times. I've tried this a number of ways, but none seem to be that incredibly efficient:

```py
import numpy 

df_corr = numpy.corrcoef(df.T)
corr_column = df_corr.iloc[:, column_index]
```

This of course calculates the entire correlation matrix, and takes ~12s on my machine; this is a problem, as I need to do this ~35,000 times (arr is changed slightly every time before creating the correlation matrix)!

I've also tried iterating over the columns individually:

```py
corr_column = numpy.zeros(len(df))

for x in df.columns:
    corr_column[x] = numpy.corrcoef(x=p_subset.iloc[:,gene_ix],y=p_subset.iloc[:,x])[0][1]
    corr_column = vals.reshape(-1,1)
```

This is slightly faster at ~10s per iteration, but still  too slow. Are there ways to find the correlation coefficient between a column and all other columns faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can just implement the formula yourself:

```py
import numpy as np

def corr(a, i):
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    a: numpy array
    i: column index

    Returns
    -------
    c: numpy array
       correlation coefficients of a[:,i] against all other columns of a
    '''

    mean_t = np.mean(a, axis=0)
    std_t = np.std(a, axis=0)

    mean_i = mean_t[i]
    std_i = std_t[i]

    mean_xy = np.mean(a*a[:,i][:,None], axis=0)

    c = (mean_xy - mean_i * mean_t)/(std_i * std_t)
    return c


a = np.random.randint(0,10, (700,36000))

%timeit corr(a,0)
608 ms ± 180 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.corrcoef(a.T)
# Actually didn't have the patience to let it finish in my machine 
# Using a smaller sample, the implementation above is 100x faster.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you will be able to read this, but I will ask anyway.  When I test your corr function with random number, the result is correct.  But when I give it my data set:  [[1066.71, 1068.91, 1070.19], [1068.91, 1070.19, 1071.08],  [1070.19, 1071.08, 1071.89]], the function returns [0.91, 0.88, 0.88], which should be [1, 1, 0.99].  Do you have any idea why?  Thank you.

Comment: Hey @ntintel, I am not able to reproduce your results in two ways:
- For starter, if I do `corr(a, 0)` I get `array([1.        , 0.99884484, 0.99228456])` and not `[0.91, 0.88, 0.88]`
- Also theoretically, I don't see why you would expect to get `[1,1, x]` as first two columns are not the same

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding.  My bad, I didn't mention  that I rounded the numbers, so your result is the same as my desired output.  Regarding the actual problem, I just found out that my dtype is float32, which produced that wrong ouput.  When I converted the input array to float64, the function gave the desired output.  So my issue is solved now, but that doesn't make sense to me, since the input numbers are well within float32 and float64.

Comment: Oh wow! Yes I can replicate this, but I am afraid I am unable to help. Any chance you can convert to f64 before the operation?
Otherwise I checked `np.corrcoef` which does not fall short on this, yet computes all pairs

Comment: yeah, i just converted my source to float64 so it's okay now.  Float32 operations, including np.corrcoef, seem to be quite a bit faster than those of float64 though.  I'm gonna miss it.