# Rewrite pd.corrwith with or without numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to correlate only the last column of an array to all other columns.  I don't want to use pd.corrwith() or np.corrcoef because pandas is slower than np.corrcoef and np.corrcoef calculates the whole matrix making it slower with a larger table.

I've tested the solutions mentioned here:

1. def coor() by FBruzzesi: [Calculate Pearson correlation coefficient for only 1 column of array efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584205/calculate-pearson-correlation-coefficient-for-only-1-column-of-array-efficiently)
2. np.corrcoef which I don't want: [Is there a numpy (or Python) function to correlate each columns of 2D numpy array (n,m): uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356720/is-there-a-numpy-or-python-function-to-correlate-each-columns-of-2d-numpy-arra)
3. def vector_corr_np() by Fillipe Maia: [How to calculate correlation between 1D numpy array and every column of a 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658716/how-to-calculate-correlation-between-1d-numpy-array-and-every-column-of-a-2d-num/73658812#73658812)

The ones that worked all returned correct results with random numbers.  However, when I tested them against my simple set of data (first column vs others):

```
array = [[1066.71, 1068.91, 1070.19], [1068.91,1070.19,1071.08], [1070.19,1071.08,1071.89]]
```

They returned [0.908, 0.879, 0.877] which was incorrect and should have been [1, 0.999, 0.992] as calculated by np.corrcoef and Excel.

Could someone help me out on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Which approaches are "the ones that worked"?

Comment: the solutions / functions that produce results similar to np.corrcoef

Comment: Namely: def corr() by FBruzzesi, vector_corr_np() by Fillipe Maia, and some other methods using np.corrcoef, which  I don't want.

Comment: In your example, that looks like the correlation of the *first* column with *all* the columns. I get your results when I make `array` a NumPy array and call `pearsonr2(array[:, 0:1], array)` with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817623/improve-speed-of-scipy-pearson-correlation-for-many-pairwise-calculations/78025304#78025304

Comment: @Matt: Thanks Matt for pointing that out.  I added your clarification to the post.

Comment: Does that linked answer meet your needs? If not, please let us know the shortcoming in your post.

Comment: @Matt.  After our discussion on my previous question, I switched my data to float32 instead of float64 to shave off a few minutes.  That turned out to be the problem with self written code while np.corrcoef still works out fine.  When I switch dtype back to float64, these functions produce matching output with np.corrcoef.  Now that I don't understand.

Comment: Not all implementations are equally numerically stable. If you can provide example data that the linked answer does not work with (with a test that does not pass), I can provide a more stable implementation.

Comment: @Matt: I just ran your pearson2() function against my data and it indeed returned the correct correlation, so it is a solution.  Can I ask you what made yours work fine with float32 while others do not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem underlies in my data, which was float32.  But I when switch to float64, the functions produce correct results that match np.corrcoef's.  It's a fix for this situation, but I don't understand why changing dtype like this would work.